# iText 5 BaseFont.Create fails with Encoding error not recognized

Tags: vb.net, fonts, itext

I am trying to add NeutraText font to my PDF document created using iText5 but receive an error saying the encoding isn't recognized. The error occurs on the last line below.

```
Dim fontDir = Server.MapPath("~/Fonts")
FontFactory.RegisterDirectory(fontDir)
Dim myFontBase = BaseFont.CreateFont("neutratext-lightalt", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, True)
```

The exact error reads

> "Font 'neutratext-lightalt' with 'Identity-H' is not recognized"

I tried a few of the BaseFont encodings and all seem to fail. Anyone looking for the font you can find it [here](http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Neutra-Text-Book)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded `Neutra Text Book.otf`, and I ran this code:

```
public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/Neutra Text Book.otf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, "", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    String[] encoding = bf.getCodePagesSupported();
    for (int i = 0; i < encoding.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(encoding[i]);
    }
}
```

I got the following output:

> 1252 Latin 1
>
> 1253 Greek

This might explain the error you get. This means that `"Cp1252"` and `"Cp1253"` are supported. If you want to use characters that aren't known in these code pages, those characters won't show up.

No problem occured when I tried `IDENTITY_H`: iText was smart enough to map the available glyphs to their Unicode value. So what wrong?

I was able to reproduce the problem you mention by changing the following line:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, "", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

To this line:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("neutratext-lightalt", "", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

The error you receive doesn't mean you have the wrong encoding as you initially thought. It just means that `"neutratext-lightalt"` can't be used as a parameter when creating a `BaseFont` object. (By the way: when I checked the font name of `"Neutra Text Book.otf"`, I got `"NeutraText-Book"` as result, not `"neutratext-lightalt"`.)

To solve the problem, you need something like this:

```
public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/Neutra Text Book.otf";
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

I know that you registered the fonts with the `FontFactory`, but when you do so, you are supposed to get the `Font` object from that `FontFactory` using the `FontFactory.getFont()` method, not by using the `BaseFont.createFont()` method.

**Update:**

In the comments, the OP claims that the proposed solution doesn't work.

The following screen shot should be sufficient proof that this claim isn't correct:

[image]

Comment: Initially I did use FontFactory.getFont() but when the PDF rendered the fonts did not display as it should. This is why I am now trying to embed and see if it helps. Unless you have another suggestion?

Comment: Explain "Did not display as it should" because your assumptions about what should display might be wrong. This isn't a font that is able to display much more than Latin and Greek characters.

Comment: I am using the font to create a list of names, example "Bob, Jane, Mary". The rendered font looks like Arial instead of NeutraText. I changed the font to SegoeUI and I can see the font as it should be.

Comment: The best way to see which font is used is to look at Document Properties > Fonts. Note that Helvetica (very similar to Arial) is used as the default font whenever the font of choice can't be found. I assume that you are instantiating the NeutraText font incorrectly. I'll make an example with the NeutraText font, and I'll update my answer with a screen shot.

Comment: @BDays See the screen shot I added to my answer. My code works. If your code doesn't, show your code.

Comment: I see it works, my comment was "Initially I did use FontFactory.getFont() but when the PDF rendered the fonts did not display as it should" I was continuing to ask if you think my process regarding that approach would have been wrong. I tried your solution and it does in fact work as you described.

Comment: OK, embedding is necessary in most cases, because there is no guarantee that someone receiving a document with a specific font also has access to that font.

Comment: Yea i get that, but why does it not render on the machine where the font is installed on? Sorry if I am crossing into a different question

Comment: Either because the font can't be found (wrong location or installed incorrectly), or because the wrong font name is used.